# force file download code work on localhost but not working on actual server in php

Tags: php, image

I'm php programmer of beginner. I have write code to download file of any type.

When I click on download link it goes to download.php file. I work on local server but not working on server.

My code is:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');    //application/force-download
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit();
```

Is my code wrong or does server need some settings?

Comment: I am not much more aware for PHP,but please check the path on server and authentication.Because I face same problem on Asp.net.

Comment: you have to define what is `not working`

Comment: What is `$file`, does it exist on the server?

Comment: done any debugging? obviously if the code works in one place but not another, then **SOMETHING** is different between the two environments. Since you've provided no useful details, we can at best guess or offer blanket "check for errors" type statements.

Comment: my code run very well on locallhost. but it not working on server, is there any setting requires......

Comment: @satyawan If you have found the solution Please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is code tested online its working fine. u can try this

```
$folder_name = $_GET['fol_name'];
$file_directory = "../img/files/$folder_name"; //Name of the directory where all the sub directories and files exists

$file = $_GET['file_name']; //Get the file from URL variable

$file_array = explode('/', $file); //Try to seperate the folders and filename from the path
$file_array_count = count($file_array); //Count the result
$filename = $file_array[$file_array_count-1]; //Trace the filename
$file_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$file_directory.'/'.$file; //Set the file path w.r.t the download.php... It may be different for u

if(file_exists($file_path)) {
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}"); //Tell the filename to the browser
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream'); //Stream as a binary file! So it would force browser to download
    readfile($file_path); //Read and stream the file
}
else {
    echo "Sorry, the file does not exist!";
}
```

thank u !!

Answer (score 0):

by using code written by me. this problem is solved.
if anybody have same issue. please try this code. it works for me very good.

```
$file_name ='../img/files'.DS.$_GET['file'];
if(is_file($file_name)) {
        if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { 
                ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'ON');       
        }
        switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
                case 'pdf':  $mime = 'application/pdf'; break; // pdf files
                case 'zip':  $mime = 'application/zip'; break; // zip files
                case 'jpeg': $mime = 'image/jpeg'; break;// images jpeg
                case 'jpg':  $mime = 'image/jpg'; break;
                case 'mp3':  $mime = 'audio/mpeg'; break; // audio mp3 formats
                case 'doc':  $mime = 'application/msword'; break; // ms word
                case 'avi':  $mime = 'video/x-msvideo'; break;  // video avi format
                case 'txt':  $mime = 'text/plain'; break; // text files
                case 'xls':  $mime = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'; break; // ms excel
                default: $mime = 'application/force-download';
        }
    header('Content-Type:application/force-download');
        header('Pragma: public');       // required
        header('Expires: 0');           // no cache
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: private',false);
        header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        //header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));      // provide file size
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile($file_name);           
        exit();
}
```

thank u!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But this code prints the output but not forcing to download. in local it does works fine

Comment: please try absolute path of image instead of relative.

Comment: hi satish , i have update new code for file download. its test online working fine. u can use it

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this problem and discovered that this was being caused by ob_clean();
 and flush(); These are causing the program to download garbage.

I tried various combinations to flush the buffer and the only one which worked on the hosting server was 
ob_end_clean(); 
print $object->body;

It might work with echo as well but i didn't try it

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
public function loadfile($fl)
    { 
        $mime = 'application/force-download';
        header('Pragma: public');   // required
        header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Cache-Control: private',false);
        header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fl).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile($fl);      // push it out
        exit();
}
```

Comment: check your file path in $fl 
eg img/aa.jpg (dont use full path with domain name )

Comment: when i click on download link then it goes to download.php page and not getting any arror only blank page seen and file not download.

Comment: how did you send $file value in download.php ? using post or get method